# changing column from CHAR(18) to CHAR(36) IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, char, primary-key

My MysQL DB was using for a primary key `CHAR(18)` but it was needed to change this data type to `CHAR(36)`. However, if, with the mouse and using Workbench, I make a 'Copy Field' at a cell of the new `CHAR(36)` column I get the old string with 18 chars. I checked the declaration of this column and it says `CHAR(36)` PK. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the key after changing the column type? If not, it was only able to handle 16 characters upon creation of the row, so the rest of the data is truncated / lost.

Usually you'll get a DataTruncation-Eception if this appears, but ofc. if you didn't handle this type of exception, the data is inserted anyway - just truncated.

You cannot restore this information, unless you have a full query-log enabled which would allow you to recreate the Primary-Key from the logs.

At least it's a PK-Column (unique), so if the insertion worked, also the truncated part of the key was unique, which allows you to "fix it manually".

Comment: The data was in a spreadsheet and I created the DB schema first. The original data for IDs had 18 chars and it was "inserted " like that. The "just created" new schema declared IDs as CHAR(36).

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga is it really `CHAR()` what you are using or `VARCHAR()`? Keep in Mind, that the length for `VARCHAR` is given in bytes, so a `VARCHAR(36)` along with an encoding requiring 2 bytes per character can only hold 18 characters.

Comment: I am sure it is CHAR